# Order by Datefield only in Django

Tags: django, date

I want to sort by `DateTimeField` ignoring one hour.
Because in my ordination I need

```
Person.objects.order_by('-date_joined', 'full_name')
```

Sorting by name has no effect because it is a Timefield , but I wanted to data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your Django version (1.9+), this should work:

```
Person.objects.order_by ('-date_joined__date','full_name')
```

Otherwise you can use `.extra` to cast into `date` field:

```
Person.objects.extra(
    select={'joined_date': 'DATE(myapp_person.date_joined)'},
    order_by=['-joined_date', 'full_name'],
)
```

Comment: `Person.objects.extra(select={'joined_date': 'DATE(date_joined)'}).order_by('-joined_date', 'full_name')`